# Get timeStamp & uuid value from metadata line in the XFA of PDF form

Tags: javascript, xml, uuid, acrobat, xfa

I have a dynamic XFA form that contains 3 pages of fields to fill. I used software called iText to extract the XFA into a .XML file. Here are the first two lines within the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xdp:xdp xmlns:xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/" timeStamp="2014-04-21T13:54:22B" uuid="y9084hcba-83jna4-b83-h2g6-92ncna8n3n2la9">
```

Is there a way to extract the values of `timeStamp` and `uuid` by writing a .js  file into Adobe's folder level? Currently I'm exporting the XML using the following javascript code, using a trusted function.

You can see how it saves "savedform.xml" to desktop. **What code could I include below that would get the timeStamp & uuid values and write them to a separate text file also on the desktop?**

I've tried displaying an alert with the code `xfa.resolveNode("xdp:xdp.timeStamp");` and 
`var x = document.getElementsByTagName("xdp:xdp")[0].getAttribute("timeStamp");` but no luck.

Thanks a lot

```
var myTrustFunct = app.trustedFunction(function(doc)
{
     app.beginPriv();
        doc.exportXFAData({
          cPath:"/c/Users/ME/Desktop/savedForm.xml",
          bCopy: true,
          bPromptToOverwrite: false,
          bXDP:false
                  });
     app.endPriv();
     return;
});
```

Comment: A little bit convoluted, but it should work: After exporting the XML, import it again as a Data Object, get its contents either in a string variable or a field, and then use a suitable Regular Expression to extract the information, or use the last remaining pieces of E4X to analyze the XML data. Then create another Data Object with the extracted data in the way you want it. Finally export that Data Object to a file, and delete the imported and created Data Objects.

Comment: I've been meaning to thank you Max. I'm just now getting a minute to test your suggestion. Appreciate the input

Comment: That's all fine; I'be interested to hear your results.

Comment: Hi Max, your suggestion seems plausible, however the code in my original question exports form data to an XML file, yet this XML file doesn't contain the timeStamp line referenced above. Only when I use iText am I able to extract the "full" xml, which includes thousands more lines including the initial timeStamp line. When I use Acrobat's "Export Data" option in the Tools menu it also creates the full XML, yet the "exportXFAData" only exports the form, subform which includes: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfa:data xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/"` Suggestions? Thx

Comment: Edit: Actually, Acrobat's "Export Data" option does *not* create a full xml, but merely creates the form>subform xml like my code above.. However iText is able to get the "Full" xml including timeStamp using this code: http://pastebin.com/9W5qZK56 .. How can I get the full XML using Acrobat's Javascript? Thank you

Comment: Update: I've found a work-around that doesn't require this timeStamp alteration at all. Thanks Max.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it to work, @Hurmle.